# Dropdown list with autocomplete and instant results

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I want to create a dropdown list with autocomplete.
The list will contain districts from a country, and when a user selects a certain district, he should be able to see right away a list of other members from that district, and some data about them, from the database.

Once the district has been selected, the results should always be shown on the page, even in new sessions, until the user changes his settings.

What would be the simplest or the most efficient solution for this?
Thanks.

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: It seems like based on your tags, you already know the most efficient solution, and you're probably getting downvoted because this site isn't for doing the work for you, it's for helping you get through rough spots you don't understand.  That being said, depending on the data set, I'd either get the results in advance, or get them via AJAX on demand, use jQuery for the autocomplete (and AJAX), and use PHP to store session variables for persistence.

Comment: Please stop downvoting - it is a just a habbit. Untill now, this user knows what to do. Better help her/him with some advices like @SLoW

Comment: Thanks for the advices. I just need to know what technical options and alternatives are for performing this task, and how other proffesionals see that this could be done. It is a question about developer vision. Any opinion is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll add an answer based on my comment and expand on it a little bit with documentation:

For the auto complete, jQuery UI has that already built into it, and I've had good luck with it in the past.

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

You still have to populate the autocomplete information, and like I said in my comment, you either need to serve the entire data set (of what the user can choose) when you serve the page, or if that's too much data all at once, perhaps get it as the user types with AJAX (kind of like google instant search does).

The jQuery documentation is really good, so you can see how to do AJAX with it here: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Regarding persistence across pages, a PHP session variable would work, but you say you want it to work across sessions, so you might want to consider a cookie instead and make sure that you set the expiration to match the desired behavior.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php

I hope this helps.  As you begin to implement, feel free to come back and ask a new question, just make sure you state clearly what you've tried, what it's currently doing, and what it needs to be doing.  That's the best way to make sure you get a high quality answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good way to start : https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete